# Enable jquery support in Komodo Edit

Tags: komodoedit

How can I enable jquery support (auto complete, function description) in Komodo Edit?

Comment: Hey Paul, Komodo was just updated and now has jquery 1.6.1 in the API catalog. If you don't have yours set to autoupdate you need to run the update.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Click the Edit menu item then Preferences at the bottom of the menu. When the preference box pops up click Code Intelligence. At the bottom is the list of catalogs - select Jquery.